# How do I set read timeouts on java Socket/SSLSocket?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ssl, timeout

If I have a connected socket and and it is waiting(blocking) to receive some data from the remote machine but somehow or other, the remote machine loses its connection, how can I make it such that it stops blocking but times out after a certain period of time without receiving any data? I'm using a Scanner object to read data from the socket and a PrintWriter object to write,

```
// Get InputStream
scanner = new Scanner( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
// Get OutputStream
printWriter = new PrintWriter( clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true );
```

Comment: have a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using socket, you can [set timeout option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: @normalocity - your edit makes no sense, the method is clearly evident in the javadoc you link to. Rolling it back.

Comment: Hm - must be getting a case of the blinds today. No worries.

Comment: but when I read from the socket using scanner.nextLine(), its specification shows that it does not throw any SocketTimeoutException, how then would I detect when a timeout has occurred?

Comment: The underlying InputStream that you're passing to the constructor will throw the exception. The timeout exception is not declared in the Scanner class because the Scanner class isn't the one throwing the exception in this case. It'll still bubble-up in your stack trace. Just try it - you'll see. :)